# Error : 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: apache, file-upload, nginx

I have built my video uploading website on Dedicated Server. I have installed Ubuntu 14.0 and Plesk Panel. Plesk Panel is working with Nginx and Apache. I got an "Error : 413 Request Entity Too Large" error message while uploading videos larger than 128 MB.

How do I increase the per-file upload limit to 1GB?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it with init_set() in your php file-

```
ini_set('MAX_FILE_UPLOAD');
```

OR you can try with .htaccess file. Put below line in your htaccess file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
```

Comment: I was tried these things and got the error again. I have disabled the Nginx, now i can upload the files more than 128 MB. Problem from Nginx only.

Comment: it depends on your server config.because if you have configured your Apache as a dynamic web server it should works.